# Reading folders in x86

Tags: file, assembly, x86

I want to know if there is a way to read the name of sub-folders and files of given path recursively in assembly x86

Comment: What Operating System? Or in case you want to run without an operating system: What File System?

Comment: "folders" and "subfiles" are not defined in x86 assembly.  They are instead, parts of various operating system APIs/ABIs such as DOS, Win32, Unix, and so forth.  In each of these, one can of course access the APIs using assembly language.

Comment: I am using windows
How can i use windows API to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call [FindFirstFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx) (or FindFirstFileEx()), [FindNextFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(v=VS.85).aspx) (or FindNextFileEx()) and [FindClose()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364413(v=VS.85).aspx).

Generic examples of how to call the Windows API in assembler can be found [elsewhere on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023593/how-to-write-hello-world-in-assembler-under-windows).