# Printing a character to standard output in Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, printing, x86

I'm a little confused about how to print a character to the screen using Assembly. The architecture is x86 (linux). Is it possible to call one of the C functions or is there a simpler way? The character I want to output is stored in a register.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, you can use any normal C function. Here's a NASM example that uses [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) to print some output:

```
;
; assemble and link with:
; nasm -f elf test.asm && gcc -m32 -o test test.o
;
section .text

extern printf   ; If you need other functions, list them in a similar way

global main

main:

    mov eax, 0x21  ; The '!' character
    push eax
    push message
    call printf
    add esp, 8     ; Restore stack - 4 bytes for eax, and 4 bytes for 'message'
    ret

message db 'The character is: %c', 10, 0
```

If you only want to print a single character, you could use [putchar](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putchar):

```
push eax
call putchar
```

---

If you want to print out a number, you could do it like this:

```
mov ebx, 8
push ebx
push message
call printf
...    
message db 'The number is: %d', 10, 0
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if register ebx holds the value 8, and I want to print the character '8'. If I try and push ebx as the parameter it doesn't work so is there a way around this? Cheers

Comment: that would be equivalent to `printf("%d", 8);` I added that to the answer

Answer (score 11):

In the interest of completeness, here is how to do it without C.

## Using DOS interrupts

[AH = 02h -WRITE CHARACTER TO STANDARD OUTPUT](http://spike.scu.edu.au/%7Ebarry/interrupts.html#ah02)

Writes character in `DL`. (I tested this with the DOS emulator [emu2](https://github.com/dmsc/emu2))

```
mov dl, 21h ; char '!'
mov ah, 02h ; char output service
int 21h     ; call DOS services
```

## x86-32 Linux `write` syscall

[`write`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) requires the address of your string. For a single character you can push your character on the stack.

```
push    '!'         ; push dword
mov     eax, 4      ; write call number, __NR_write from unistd_32.h
mov     ebx, 1      ; write to stdout (fd=1)
mov     ecx, esp    ; use char on stack
mov     edx, 1      ; write 1 char
int     0x80        ; call into the kernel
add     esp, 4      ; restore sp
```

[Info on register order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/3163618)

## x86-64 Linux `write` syscall

Similar to above, but the call number is now 1, `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`, and the calling convention registers are different.

```
push    '!'         ; push qword 0x21
mov     rax, 1      ; write call number, __NR_write from unistd_64.h
mov     edi, 1      ; write to stdout (int fd=1)
mov     rsi, rsp    ; use char on stack
mov     rdx, 1      ; size_t len = 1 char to write.
syscall            ; call the kernel, it looks at registers to decide what to do
add     rsp, 8      ; restore stack pointer
```

`mov edx, 1` does exactly the same thing as `mov rdx, 1`, but NASM will optimize it for you.  This code uses operand-sizes that match the C types, not optimizing mov of small non-negative 64-bit integers.

Comment: For x86-64 Linux, you can `lea -1(%rsp), %rsi` / `movb $0x21, (%rsi)` to use the red-zone, and not have to pop the stack.

Comment: and what about for X86-64 Windows?  (21h calls are blocked.)

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 I don't know about Windows, sorry. Maybe Peter Cordes can shed some light.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83: Windows has a system-call ABI you can in theory use from user-space, but it's undocumented and not stable across versions.  Still, see https://github.com/j00ru/windows-syscalls for reverse-engineering details.  I don't know which one(s) you'd actually want to use.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83: In general for Windows you *don't* want to use a raw system-call directly, you want to call a DLL function.  [How to write hello world in assembly under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1023593) shows how for 32 and 64-bit executables with a variety of APIs and assemblers.

Answer (score -3):

Calling [`putchar(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putchar) is the simplest way. Just move the char's value into the `rdi` register (for x86-64, or `edi` for x86), and call `putchar`.

E.g. (for x86-64):

```
asm("movl $120, %rdi\n\t"
    "call putchar\n\t");
```

will print an `x` to stdout.

Comment: Wrong ABI!  (x86-64 OS X, at a guess, given the register -- although I think you want `%rdi` not `%edi` -- and the leading `_` on the library function?)

Comment: You changed it in the code, but your description still says "the edi register."

Comment: The i386 System V calling convention passes args on the stack, and EDI is a call-preserved register.  Plus doing this from GNU C "basic" inline asm (with no clobbers) isn't safe: you step on the compilers registers.  And for x86-64, you step on the compiler's red-zone, too.  This *will* call `putchar` on x86-64 Linux, but that's all, what happens after that is unpredictable.

Comment: @MatthewSlattery: `movl` to `%edi` is a more efficient way to zero-extend a value into RDI.  As it stands now, this won't even assemble (mismatch between `movl` dword operand size suffix vs. qword register).  But anyway, without any clobbers this is totally broken.  See my previous comment.  In stand-alone asm, `mov $'x', %edi` ; `call putchar` this would be fine.