# Assembly: What is the best way to print something to screen (to command line)

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, exe, masm

I've been doing some research, but I only find more and more ways to do what I want and I don't understand any of them.

What code do I need to assemble into an .exe to return `5` to the command line?

I want an exe that, when called, prints `5` .

Research:

```
printf "5", 0
```

It requires to link with 2 libraries, and I want to keep it simple.

```
move ebx, 5 ; or move ax, 5
ret
```

Why would this print `5` ? This loads a register whith a value `5` and returns. Nothing else.

Could someone explain me the difference between those ways of returning `5`?

What would be most appropiate for a very simple Windows EXE executable?

I couldn't get the answers in the questions already asked in StackOverflow.

NOTE, I use: Win 7, WinAsam, MASM

THANKS!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing a character to standard output in Assembly x86](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201613/printing-a-character-to-standard-output-in-assembly-x86)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use printf?  On windows, it is part of the MS C Runtime that is part of windows now.

Using the Windows API, you would use:

`GetStdHandle`

And one of the following:

`WriteConsole`

`WriteConsoleOutput`

`WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`

`WriteConsoleOutputCharacter`

`WriteFile`

All depends on how you want to do it.

`mov`ing something into a register does not print anything, you have to tell the OS to print it.

If you find something that you don't understand, do some research on it, read the documentation, code comments, play around with the code changing things and see how it works.