# Assembly on Windows

Tags: windows, assembly

I am interested in doing minimal assembly programming on Windows. No GUI, just a plain old `.exe` program that will print a few characters to the console. In order to see if it was even possible to simply compile and run assembly on Windows, I tried the following:

test.s:

```
ret
```

command line:

```
gcc test.s
```

And I got the following error:

> In function 'main': undefined reference to 'WinMain'

So the question is how do I go about compiling a simple assembly do-nothing program to a Windows executable? Do I need to define `WinMain` in every program? Is it a flag to `gcc`?

I don't really care which assembler I use, but if someone knows if this is the same of different for `gcc`(`gas`), `masm` and other assemblers, that would be nice, too.

Comment: I'd recommend getting masm32 and working with that.

Comment: you might want to start by looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023593/how-to-write-hello-world-in-assembler-under-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you want *pure* or *clean* assembly, is this along those lines?

taken from [The Assembly Programmers Master Book](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2048131.The_Assembly_Programming_Master_Book)
language `masm32` assembler,linker `ml,link`

source;

```
.586P
; Flat memory model
.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL
;---------------------------------------
; Data segment
_DATA SEGMENT

_DATA ENDS
; Code segment
_TEXT SEGMENT
START:
    RET  ; Exit
_TEXT ENDS
END START
```

assembly & linking;

```
ML /c /coff PROG1.ASM
LINK /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS PROG1.0BJ
```

This program was literally called "Do Nothing" but it is *pure* masm that just does nothing.

If you want to program in **windows** without the help of C you will have to program with the WIN32 api, you can find a reference to this api on the net called `win.hlp` `win32.hlp`, it would appear to be on this [web-page](http://www.modula2.org/win32tutor/references.php)

Perhaps a handy link -> [MASM 6.1 Documentation](http://people.sju.edu/~ggrevera/arch/references/MASM61PROGUIDE.pdf)

---

EDIT: Using `as` (*gas*) & `ld`;

```
.globl _start

_start: // ld looks for _start by default
    movl $22, %eax // AT&T syntax
    ret
```

compile;

```
c:\Users\James\Desktop\asm\>as file.s

c:\Users\James\Desktop\asm\>ld a.out

c:\Users\James\Desktop\asm\>a.exe

c:\Users\James\Desktop\asm\>echo %errorlevel%
22
```

Disassembly of section .text:

```
00401000 <_start>:
  401000:       b8 16 00 00 00          mov    $0x16,%eax
  401005:       c3                      ret
  401006:       90                      nop
  401007:       90                      nop
```

---

Simply putting `ret` is not going to get you far, you can get the assembly listings of your c/c++ programs by compiling with the `-S` flag (`-masm=intel` gives you intels syntax).

That said you need to specify an `entry point` for the linker to know where the code begins, you also need to create a `text segment` for the code, here is a *really really* simple example that returns `1`;

```
    .text
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .globl _main

_main: // entry point!
    mov eax, 1
    ret
```

`gcc [file].s` yeilds `a.exe`

Comment: Also, compiling with -S will give me assembly that needs to link with the C standard library. I want clean assembly

Comment: I don't know how you got errors, i just compiled that code on two different computers under both linux and windows???

Comment: I tried it on Windows and got that error. Which gcc are you using?

Comment: typing in `gcc --version` output `gcc (rev2, Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`, ill edit in another way using `as` & `ld`