# Can Someone explain me how this NASM Program works?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

This is the code i copied from a [Stackoverflow.com's Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1029093/3512216):

```
global _main
    extern  _GetStdHandle@4
    extern  _WriteFile@20
    extern  _ExitProcess@4

    section .text
_main:
    ; DWORD  bytes;    
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 4

    ; hStdOut = GetstdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    push    -11
    call    _GetStdHandle@4
    mov     ebx, eax    

    ; WriteFile( hstdOut, message, length(message), &bytes, 0);
    push    0
    lea     eax, [ebp-4]
    push    eax
    push    (message_end - message)
    push    message
    push    ebx
    call    _WriteFile@20

    ; ExitProcess(0)
    push    0
    call    _ExitProcess@4

    ; never here
    hlt
message:
    db      'Hello, World', 10
message_end:
```

This Code works correctly, No errors needs to be cleared, But there have some lines which im unable to understand what does they do, Scroll down:

```
MOV ebp, esp
```

Okay anyone can tell this copies the contents of `esp` to `ebp` register, But how can this be possible to copy a uninitialised register's value to a register? Will it load `ebp` with a `0` (Zero)?

```
SUB esp, 4
```

Here `esp` is being subtracted by `4`, So `0-4= -4`, Is'nt it?? But why this Two lines of code? instead if the result is to be the result which i given `"-4"` i would have Normaly do `MOV esp, -4`

```
MOV ebx, eax
```

And the `eax`, which i think must be filled by `_GetstdHandle` function?

and the last one, `hlt`?

Comment: `esp` isn't uninitialized. When your application is started, a stack is created for its main thread, and `esp` will point to the top of that stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. esp can never be "uninitialized". It always points to the top of the stack - where you push and pop things. For example, when you push a 32 bit register, esp is automatically decreased by four.
2. The "sub esp, 4" allocates four bytes on the stack - for the "bytes" variable. Later you can see "lea ax, [ebp-4]", which corresponds to "&bytes" in the comment.
3. Quite right, eax is returned from _GetStdHandle.
4. "hlt" halts the processor - a bad thing. But as the comment says - is wll not be executed since _ExitProcess won't return. The idea might be that *if* _ExitProcess should return, it is better to halt than to start execute random code.

Comment: The "hlt" instruction would not work in a Windows program at all. It would wait for the next interrupt if called from kernel context. Because it is a privileged instruction it would cause a fault when being called from a user-mode program!

Answer (score 2):

Summarized, this program creates a stack frame with one local variable, then calls Win32 API functions from kernel32.lib imported by the 'extern's above and exits with SUCCESS (0).

```
mov ebp, esp
```

sets the base pointer register with the current value of SS:ESP. This is done for accessing the local DWORD variable (4 bytes) reserved with

```
sub esp, 4
```

The stack grows downwards, for example: if ESP is 0FFFF0000h set by the OS on program start, EBP will be set to this value and the substraction will decrease it to 0FFFEFFFCh giving space for the local 4 byte var @ this address, which will be referenced later by

```
lea     eax, [ebp-4]      ; &bytes
```

The line

```
mov ebx, eax
```

saves the handle in EAX in EBX (which is not neccessary in this case), because

```
Registers EBP, EBX, ESI, and EDI are preserved during Win32 API calls.
```

The HLT at the end is unreachable code and therefore should never be executed. Anyway, it would stop the further execution, see here: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/HLT.html