# Passing Params From One Proc to Another in x86 Assembly

Tags: windows, assembly

so im having trouble understanding how to pass parameters from one proc to another, both in a different .asm file. Im using TASM on a 64 bit.

So lets say i have a main proc:

```
extrn   addproc: proc, putint: proc
main    proc    
mov ax, n  ;where n is an integer
call    addproc
main    endp
 end    main
```

how would i send `n` to addproc and use it to add 2 to it (just for example)

```
addproc proc    
add ax, 2
addproc endp
 end    addproc
```

Comment: That for example should work fine, even if it isn't the standard convention.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#x86) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions).

Comment: @Jester what is the standard convention?

Comment: @User.1 the addproc? or both?

Comment: Just addproc.  Unless you are using the c runtime library, main should end with a call to the windows exit process function.  That's something that higher level languages do for you.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1023600/2189500