# What are R10-R15 registers used for in the Windows x64 calling convention?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

From Intel's introduction to x64 assembly at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly,

- RCX, RDX, R8, R9 are used for integer and pointer arguments in that order left to right.
- Registers RAX, RCX, RDX, R8, R9, R10, and R11 are considered volatile and must be considered destroyed on function calls.
- RBX, RBP, RDI, RSI, R12, R14, R14, and R15 must be saved in any function using them.

While I understand how RCX, RDX, R8, R9 are used as function arguments, I've seen functions that take more than 4 arguments revert to using the stack like 32 bit code. An example is below:

```
sub_18000BF10   proc near 
lpDirectory     = qword ptr -638h
nShowCmd        = dword ptr -630h
Parameters      = word ptr -628h

             sub     rsp, 658h
             mov     r9, rcx
             mov     r8, rdx
             lea     rdx, someCommand ; "echo "Hello""...
             lea     rcx, [rsp+658h+Parameters] ; LPWSTR
             call    cs:wsprintfW
             xor     r11d, r11d
             lea     r9, [rsp+658h+Parameters] ; lpParameters
             mov     [rsp+658h+nShowCmd], r11d ; nShowCmd
             lea     r8, aCmdExe     ; "cmd.exe"
             lea     rdx, Operation  ; "open"
             xor     ecx, ecx        ; hwnd
             mov     [rsp+658h+lpDirectory], r11 ; lpDirectory
             call    cs:ShellExecuteW
             mov     eax, 1
             add     rsp, 658h
             retn
sub_18000BF10    endp
```

This is an excerpt from IDA, and you can see the nShowCmd and lpDirectory arguments to ShellExecute are on the stack. **Why cant we use the extra registers after R9 for fast-call behavior?**

Or if we can do that in user-defined functions and the system API functions don't do that, is there a reason for it? I imagine fast-call arguments in registers would be more efficient than checking, offsetting the stack.

Comment: Yes in your own convention you can use them. Microsoft decided to only allow 4 registers. SysV uses 6, including `r9`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows x64 calling convention is designed to make it easy to implement variadic functions (like printf and scanf) by dumping the 4 register args into the shadow space, creating a contiguous array of all args.  Args larger than 8 bytes are passed by reference, so each arg always takes exactly 1 arg-passing slot.

**Given this design constraint, more register args would require a larger [shadow space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273797/shadow-space-example), which wastes more stack space for small functions that don't have a lot of args.**

Yes, more register args would normally be more efficient.  But if the callee wants to make another function call right away with different args, it would then have to store all its register args to the stack or copy to call-preserved regs it saved, so there are downsides to having to register args that get worse as you have more of them.

**You want a good mix of [call-preserved and call-clobbered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers/56178078#56178078) registers, regardless of how many are used for arg-passing**.  R10 and R11 are call-clobbered scratch regs.  A transparent wrapper function written in asm might use them for scratch space without disturbing any of the args in RCX,RDX,R8,R9, and without needing to save/restore a call-preserved register anywhere.

R12..R15 are call-preserved registers you can use for whatever you want, as long as you restore them before returning.  Same as RSI, RDI, RBX, and RBP.

---

> Or if we can do that in user-defined functions

Yes, you can freely make up your own calling conventions when calling from asm to asm, subject to constraints imposed by the OS.  But if you want exceptions to be able to unwind the stack *through* such a call (e.g. if one of the child functions calls back into some C++ that can throw), you have to follow more restrictions, such as creating unwind metadata.  If not, you can do nearly anything.

See my [Choose your calling convention to put args where you want them.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/165020#165020) answer on the CodeGolf Q&A "Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code".

You can also return in whatever register(s) you want, and return multiple values.  (e.g. an asm `strcmp` or `memcmp` function can return the -/0/+ difference in the mismatch in EAX, *and* return the mismatch position in RDI, so the caller can use either or both.)

---

### A useful exercise in evaluating a design is to compare it to other actual or possible designs

**By comparison, the x86-64 System V ABI passes the first 6 integer args in registers, *and* the first 8 FP args in XMM0..7**.  (Windows x64 passes the 5th arg on the stack, even if it's FP and the first 4 args were all integer.)

So the other major x86-64 calling convention does use more arg-passing registers.  It doesn't use shadow-space; it defines a red-zone below RSP that's safe from being asynchronously clobbered.  Small leaf functions can still avoid manipulating RSP to reserve space.

Fun fact: R10 and R11 are also non-arg-passing call-clobbered registers in x86-64 SysV.  Fun fact #2: `syscall` destroys R11 (and RCX), so Linux uses R10 instead of RCX for passing arguments to system calls, but otherwise uses the same register-arg passing convention as user-space function calls.

See also [Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86) for more guesswork and info about why Microsoft made the design choices they did with their calling convention.

x86-64 System V makes it more complex to implement variadic functions (more code to index args), but they're generally rare.  Most code doesn't bottleneck on `sscanf` throughput.  Shadow space is usually worse than a red-zone.  The original Windows x64 convention doesn't pass vector args (`__m128`) by value, so there's a 2nd 64-bit calling convention on Windows called `vectorcall` that allows efficient vector args.  (Not usually a big deal because most functions that take vector args are inline, but SIMD math library functions would benefit.)

Having more args passed in the low 8 (rax..rdi original registers that don't need a REX prefix), and having more call-clobbered registers that don't need a REX prefix, is probably good for code-size in code that inlines enough to not make a huge amount of function calls.  You could say that Window's choice of having more of the non-REX registers be call-preserved is better for code with loops containing function calls, but if you're making lots of function calls to short callees, then they'd benefit from more call-clobbered scratch registers that didn't need REX prefixes.  I wonder how much thought MS put into this, or if they just mostly kept things similar to 32-bit calling conventions when choosing which of the low-8 registers would be call-preserved.

One of x86-64 System V's weaknesses is having no call-preserved XMM registers, though.  So any function call requires spilling/reloading any FP vars.  Having a couple, like the low 128 or 64 bits of xmm6 and xmm7, would have been maybe good.

Comment: "Yes, you can freely make up your own calling conventions when calling from asm to asm." Within limits. The Windows platform does impose some restrictions in order to support asynchronous exceptions. For example, you cannot use memory below `esp` beyond the red zone. (Of course, if you are code golfing, you probably don't care that your program doesn't behave properly in the face of asynchronous exceptions. But if you're writing production code, you need to be aware of platform requirements.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: I meant as far as arg-passing, not how you use stack space within a function, but yeah good point about wording.  I didn't just mean for golf; as long as a function respects its caller's ABI, its internal implementation can include `call` instructions however you like.  (And BTW, Windows x64 doesn't officially have a red-zone at all below `rsp`.  In practice there might not be anything that asynchronously clobbers that space but it's not guaranteed.  Perhaps you're thinking about Itanium again, like you were last time you mentioned something about a red-zone for x64.)

Comment: I was speaking more generally. There are parts of the software conventions that apply throughout the entire lifetime of a function, not just at points where you call into the operating system. For example, you must register unwind codes if the return address is not in its default place (top of stack for x64, default return address register for RISC), or if you use nonvolatile registers. "There might not be anything that asynchronously clobbers that space." Any in-page error could clobber that space. And you cannot prevent in-page errors.

Comment: Update on Raymond's point about writing below the stack pointer: [Is it valid to write below ESP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52258402) , and his blog article [Why do we even need to define a red zone? Can’t I just use my stack for anything?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190111-00/?p=100685)