# Correctly Setting Up Stack Pointer in x64 Assembly on Windows with Masm + LOCALS

Tags: assembly, masm, masm64

I have the follow simple program I'm trying to build targeting x64 on Windows 10 building with MASM:

```
WSTR MACRO lbl:req,qstr:VARARG
LOCAL arg,unq,qot,q
    lbl LABEL WORD
    FOR arg,<qstr>
        qot SubStr <arg>,1,1
        q = 0
        IFIDNI qot,<!'>;'
            q = 1
        ELSEIFIDNI qot,<!">;"
            q = 1
        ELSE
            DW arg
        ENDIF
        IF q EQ 1
            unq SubStr <arg>,2,@SizeStr(<arg>)-2
        %   FORC c,<unq>
                DW "&c"
            ENDM
        ENDIF
    ENDM
    DW 0
ENDM

L MACRO qstr:VARARG
LOCAL sym,seg
    seg EQU <.code>
    %IFIDNI <@CurSeg>,<_DATA>
        seg EQU <.data>
    ENDIF
    .CONST
        ALIGN 4
        WSTR sym,qstr
    seg
    EXITM <OFFSET sym>
ENDM

extrn   LoadCursorW: PROC
extrn   MessageBoxW: PROC
extrn   ExitProcess: PROC
extrn   GetModuleHandleW: PROC
extrn   RegisterClassExW: PROC
extrn   CreateWindowExW: PROC
extrn   GetLastError: PROC
extrn   DefWindowProcW: PROC

.data
wstr windowClassName,"AsmTestClass",0,0
wstr windowTitle,"AsmTest",0,0

HWND_DESKTOP        textequ <0h>
MB_OK           textequ <0h>

WM_CREATE       textequ <0001h>
WM_DESTROY      textequ <0002h>
WM_SIZE         textequ <0005h>
WM_PAINT        textequ <000fh>

CS_VREDRAW      textequ <0001h>
CS_HREDRAW      textequ <0002h>

WS_OVERLAPPED   textequ <00000000h>
WS_CAPTION      textequ <00c00000h>
WS_SYSMENU      textequ <00080000h>
WS_MINIMIZEBOX  textequ <00020000h>

CW_USEDEFAULT   textequ <80000000h>

IDI_APPLICATION textequ <00007f00h>

WINDOW_WIDTH        DWORD   800
WINDOW_HEIGHT   DWORD   600

WNDCLASSEX STRUCT DWORD
  cbSize            DWORD   ?
  style             DWORD   ?
  lpfnWndProc       QWORD   ?
  cbClsExtra        DWORD   ?
  cbWndExtra        DWORD   ?
  hInstance         QWORD   ?
  hIcon             QWORD   ?
  hCursor           QWORD   ?
  hbrBackground     QWORD   ?
  lpszMenuName      QWORD   ?
  lpszClassName     QWORD   ?
  hIconSm           QWORD   ?
WNDCLASSEX ENDS

.code
main proc

LOCAL wc:WNDCLASSEX
LOCAL hWnd:QWORD
LOCAL hInstance:QWORD
LOCAL hCursor:QWORD
LOCAL ATOM:WORD

    ; hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL)
    mov     rcx, 0
    call        GetModuleHandleW
    mov     hInstance, rax

    ; hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION)
    mov     edx, IDI_APPLICATION
    xor     ecx, ecx
    call        LoadCursorW
    mov     hCursor, rax
  
    ; Setup Window Class
    mov     wc.cbSize, SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX
    mov     wc.style, CS_VREDRAW or CS_HREDRAW
    lea     rax, OFFSET WndProc
    mov     wc.lpfnWndProc, rax
    mov     wc.cbClsExtra, 0
    mov     wc.cbWndExtra, 0
    lea     rax, hInstance
    mov     wc.hInstance, rax
    mov     wc.hbrBackground, 0
    mov     wc.lpszMenuName, 0
    lea     rax, hCursor
    mov     wc.hCursor, rax
    lea     rax, windowClassName
    mov     wc.lpszClassName, rax
    mov     wc.hIconSm, 0
    lea     rcx, wc
    call        RegisterClassExW
    mov     ATOM, ax

    ; CreateWindowExW
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+88], 0               ;   lpParam
    lea     rax, hInstance
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+80], rax             ;   hInstance
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+72], 0               ;   hMenu
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+64], 0               ;   hWndParent
    mov     edx, WINDOW_HEIGHT
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+56], edx             ;   nHeight
    mov     edx, WINDOW_WIDTH
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+48], edx             ;   nWidth
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+40], CW_USEDEFAULT   ;   Y
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+32], CW_USEDEFAULT   ;   X
    mov     r9d, WS_OVERLAPPED or WS_CAPTION or WS_SYSMENU or WS_MINIMIZEBOX        ; dwStyle
    lea     r8, windowTitle                     ;   lpWindowName
    lea     rdx, windowClassName                    ;   lpClassName
    xor     ecx,ecx                             ;   dwExStyle
    call        CreateWindowExW

    cmp     rax,  0
    je      WindowFailed
    jmp     WindowSuccess
WindowFailed:
    call        GetLastError
    ; to-do check error
WindowSuccess:
    mov     hWnd, rax

    mov     rcx, HWND_DESKTOP               ; hWnd
    lea     rdx, L("Hello x64 World!",0,0)  ; lpText
    lea     r8, L("Win64 Demo",0,0)         ; lpCaption
    mov     r9d, MB_OK                      ; uType 
    call        MessageBoxW
    mov     ecx, eax                            ; uExitCode
    call        ExitProcess

main endp

WndProc proc
    LOCAL hWnd:QWORD
    LOCAL uMsg:DWORD
    LOCAL wParam:QWORD
    LOCAL lParam:QWORD
    LOCAL result:QWORD

    mov     lParam, r9
    mov     wParam, r8
    mov     uMsg, edx
    mov     hWnd, rcx
    
    ; msg handler
    cmp     uMsg,WM_CREATE
    je      create
    cmp     uMsg,WM_PAINT
    je      paint
    cmp     uMsg,WM_DESTROY
    je      destroy
    cmp     uMsg,WM_SIZE
    je      resize  

    ; default
    call        DefWindowProcW
    mov     result,rax
    jmp     finish

create:
    mov     result, 0
    jmp     finish

paint:
    mov     result, 0
    jmp     finish

destroy:
    mov     result, 0
    jmp     finish

resize:
    mov     result, 0
    jmp     finish

finish: 
    mov     rax, result
    
    ret 

WndProc endp
End
```

Masm is automatically adding the following code:

```
main proc
push        rbp  
mov         rbp,rsp  
add         rsp,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFF90h  
..
main endp

WndProc proc
push        rbp  
mov         rbp,rsp  
add         rsp,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFD8h  
...
leave
ret
WndProc endp
```

However when WndProc is routine us called an access violation is triggered on call to DefWindowProcW

I suspect this is because stack pointer is not correctly setup, but masm seems to be adding code for this. How to do this correctly?

The code added by masm

```
add         rsp,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFD8h
```

It equivalent of sub rsp,40. Which is not divisible by 16, adding sub rsp,8 to my code fixes the crash.

```
WndProc proc
    LOCAL hWnd:QWORD
    LOCAL uMsg:DWORD
    LOCAL wParam:QWORD
    LOCAL lParam:QWORD
    LOCAL result:QWORD

    sub     rsp, 8
```

Is the best way to resolve this, or is there a way for masm to auto calculate correct value / or predict what needs to be corrected in advance?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you don't add shadow space to your program. I read that for regular call you should subtract 32 from rsp, and from larger calls you subtract a multiple of 16 that covers your parameters. CreateWindow has 12 parameters, so `32 + 64` would cover your shadow space, than add it back after the call... Granted I am new to assembly and do not think I fully understand why this needs to be.

Comment: That's correct, except usually you'd wait until the very end of the function to move the stack pointer again.  Reserving `32+64` (plus an odd number of pushes to realign the stack, or an extra 8 bytes in the `sub`) at the top of function leaves you with enough space for your biggest call, and spare space above the args for others.  See [Shadow space example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33273797)

Comment: And yes, without reserving shadow space for your callees, you'll be letting them overwrite your return address, which is a problem if you later `ret` instead of `call ExitProcess`, and is sloppy if you don't comment that you're doing it intentionally in a noreturn function.

Comment: Thank you, believe it or not, I ran into the exact same error as OP. Although I didn't notice I could just subtract eight and it wouldn't crash. Wish I could give a better answer but my program still crashes.

Comment: [link](https://medium.com/@sruthk/cracking-assembly-function-prolog-and-epilog-in-x64-ea1bdc50514c) has a good example of prolog/epilog

Comment: Minimal but yeah that article looks ok from a quick skim.  Many functions `push` a few call-preserved registers like `rbx`, `rbp`, or `r12` in their prologue and pop them in the epilogue, and that's part of the total adjustment to RSP (so you need to count them for stack alignment.)  See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) and the link to Matt Godbolt's talk for more about getting compilers to make example asm for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to round rsp down to a 16 byte boundary:

```
        and     rsp,0fffffff0h
```

I tested using VS2015, and usage of LOCAL causes MASM to auto-generate that code. Using VS2015, with a wmain instead of WndProc, upon entry, the last nibble of rsp == 8, apparently anticipating that the entry code will use rbp as a frame pointer:

```
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp,rsp
```

putting rsp on a 16 byte boundary

If on entry, the last nibble of rsp is always 8, then you could use dummy LOCALS so that all the LOCALS take up 8 + some multiple of 16 bytes.

Comment: *apparently anticipating that the entry code will use rbp as a frame pointer:* - In the Windows x64 calling convention, it's guaranteed that `RSP % 16 == 8` on function entry.  (So to maintain this invariant, you need RSP aligned by 16 *before* a `call` which pushes an 8-byte return address. This also means the shadow space, and stack args if any, are 16-byte aligned.)  It's 100% normal for anything that's an actual function (which can `ret`) to have RSP % 16 on entry, and would be an ABI violation if it wasn't. Normal functions shouldn't waste instruction doing `and rsp` unless they need >=32

Comment: The same `RSP & 0xF == 8` on function entry guarantee applies to the x86-64 System V ABI.  [Why does the x86-64 / AMD64 System V ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49391001).  Fun fact: on Linux, the actual process entry point, `_start`, is entered with RSP % 16 == 0.  And it's not a function; RSP points at argc on the stack, not a return address.

Comment: @PeterCordes - For  windows 64 bit calling convention, if frame pointers are omitted on a build (assuming Visual Studio), is RSP % 16 == 8 still true on function entry?

Comment: Yes.  Using a frame pointer or not is something *purely* local to a single function, zero interaction with the ABI.  Even stack-unwinding uses separate metadata, not a chain of RBP frame pointers.  x86-64 SysV is the same in this respect, saying nothing about RBP or frame pointers, other than suggesting that `_start` zeros RBP on process entry so if other code does use frame pointers, the linked list has a 0 terminator.  (In fact, modern i386 System V is the same; ESP % 16 == 12 on entry to functions, and EBP frame pointers are not part of the ABI even for stack unwinding on exceptions.)

Comment: (Not affecting the ABI is pretty clearly necessary if you think about separately-compiled code, e.g. different .obj files built with different options, or even calls to library functions in static or DLL libraries.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - I forgot that Windows X64 has a single ABI. For 32 bit mode, I think there are 3 ABIs (stdcall, fastcall, ???), which requires all files and libraries to be compiled in a compatible matter for each of the ABI (except for internal only stuff). So it would make sense that omitting frame pointers wouldn't change Windows X64 ABI.

Comment: Windows x64 has vectorcall as well as the default fastcall.  They differ only in arg-passing for wider types like `__m128`. 
32-bit mode Windows has multiple calling conventions, yes.  There's also cdecl, vectorcall, and thiscall, possibly more.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions.  In any of these, using frame pointers or not within a function isn't part of the ABI, unless required for stack unwinding.  (Although in Win32 IIRC ESP alignment is only guaranteed to be 4 bytes, so odd/even numbers of pushes are irrelevant.)

Comment: I wouldn't really call "stdcall" a whole separate ABI, though, since per-function attributes can declare what calling convention any given function should be called with.  e.g. I think WinAPI functions are all stdcall, but variadic functions like printf must be cdecl (because stdcall is callee-pops, so it couldn't ignore extra args the format string doesn't reference like ISO C requires).  So it's normal for 32-bit Windows programs to use a mix of calling conventions on a per-function basis.