# How do I write assembly for Windows x86 using GAS?

Tags: c, windows, assembly, gcc

**Subject:** Understanding Assembly Code Generation for a Simple C Program on Windows

I've been diving into GAS assembly, primarily for 32-bit, in a guided course. To challenge myself, I wanted to work with a 64-bit program on Windows, using raw assembly without the utilities provided in my course or relying on the WSL environment. I'm facing challenges, particularly in interfacing with Windows system calls and linking with DLLs.

To gain a better understanding, I compiled a simple C program using GCC:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

`objdump -d test.exe` provided the assembly representation of the `main` function, which I tried to recreate in GAS syntax (comments with the original code):

```
.global main 
.extern __main     
.extern puts 

.text     
main: 
   push   %rbp
   mov    %rsp, %rbp
   sub    $0x20, %rsp
   call   __main
   movabs $msg, %rax        # lea    0x2b9c(%rip),%rax
   mov    %rax, %rcx        # (why??)
   call   puts
   xor    %eax, %eax        # mov    $0x0,%eax (why??)
   add    $0x20, %rsp
   pop    %rbp
   ret

.data
msg: .asciz "Hello\n"
```

```
as test.s -o test.o
gcc tes.o -o test.exe
./test.exe
```

(this program finally runs on Windows)

Given this, I have a few questions:

1. **Stack Frame Initialization:** Why does the GCC output include the stack frame initialization (`push %rbp`, `mov %rsp, %rbp`, `sub $0x20, %rsp`)?
2. **Purpose of `__main`:** Why is there a call to `__main` before the main logic of the program?
3. **Linking with Windows DLLs:** How can I interface with Windows DLL functions directly in GAS syntax?

I'd appreciate any insights or corrections related to the above assembly code and queries.

Comment: Code doesn't jump directly into `main()`, there's often a lot of stuff that has to be set up first.

Comment: @tadman I was aware of this, what I didn't know is that the `main` section calls something else inside itself...

Comment: @ugo_capeto it is minGW specific, not "plain) gcc https://godbolt.org/z/hT3T9vEz9

Comment: Cygwin and/or MinGW have `main` call an init function called `__main`, instead of having earlier CRT code call libc init functions, or having a dynamically-linked libc arrange for its init functions to be called as it's loaded. (Both of the latter things happen on Linux with glibc.)

Comment: Btw about the "why" comment: `mov eax, 0` needs 5 bytes while `xor eax, eax` needs only 2 bytes.

Comment: If you mean why did GCC's original code use an inefficient `mov    $0x0,%eax`, that's because you didn't enable `-fpeephole2` when you compiled. (It's part of `-O2` and `-Os`, so just do that.)  As for movabs vs. RIP-relative LEA, see [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012) .  You have a label on the data you're referencing, so use `lea msg(%rip), %rcx`.  (GCC debug builds load into RAX and then copy to where it's actually needed.  [Optimized builds have simpler code, look at those instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116))

Comment: Reserving 32 bytes of stack space is the shadow space for the Windows calling convention.  [What is the 'shadow space' in x64 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30190132) / [Shadow space example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33273797)

Comment: @PeterCordes this was really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

> `objdump -d test.exe` provided the assembly representation of the `main` function

No, not really.  `objdump` does a **disassembly**, and for whatever obscure reason, disassembly is such that it cannot be fed back into `as`.

To get assembly, i.e. what `gcc` generates, you can use

`> gcc -save-temps ...`

which will safe intermediate files, which are usually written to some /tmp directory. You will get:

- `*.s` assembly as generated by `gcc`, or `cpp` pre-processed assembly from `*.S` or `*.sx` (which is like from `gcc -x assembler-with-cpp ...`).
- `*.i` pre-processed C files
- `*.ii` pre-processed C++ files

The content of `*.s` is valid as input to `as`.  Also note the following:

- You can augment assembly code by various means like `-fverbose-asm` which adds high-level language source lines as assembly comments.  More information can be added by `-dp` (add insn names) or `-dP` (add insn semantics as RTL).
- It might be better to use `gcc` as (driver for) the assembler.  `gcc` is just a driver program, and if supplied with `*.s`, `*.S`, *.sx`, , '-x assembler` or `-x assembler-with-cpp`, it will call the assembler with appropriate options (after pre-processing if requested).  This might be more convenient that figuring out the options required to pass to `as` by yourself.  To see how the assembler is being called, add `-v`.
- If you want to read assembly as generated by `gcc`, it might be better to **switch off debug info** generation (`-g0`).
- When using link-time optimization (LTO as of `-flto`), then gcc will only add LTO byte-code to assembly, except with `-ffat-lto-objects`. Notice that this is not the final assembly, which will be located in some `*ltrans*.s` files.

Comment: There are disassemblers which produce output in valid NASM or GAS syntax (notably Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler, which has options for output syntax).  The raw machine code is shown as a comment after the mnemonic.  It doesn't try to make byte-identical round-trips possible, though, e.g. it doesn't use GAS `{load}` or `{store}` decorators to disambiguate opcode for reg-reg instructions, or override the immediate width like `push strict dword 123` for NASM.  It does invent label names for branch targets, though.

Comment: Also, you normally want `-Os` or `-O2`, or at least `-Og`, to make asm with less weird stuff going on for very simple code like this.  e.g. GCC loads an address into RAX then copies to RCX because that's `-O0` uses registers *very* simplistically.  See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Answer (score -2):

Given the existing discussion, I'd like to present a streamlined code that addresses my questions while still accomplishing the task:

```
.global main

.extern puts 
.extern exit

.text

main: 
   lea  msg(%rip), %rcx
   call puts

   xor  %rcx, %rcx
   call exit
   ret

.data

msg: .asciz "Hello World!\n"
```

To compile (or more accurately, to assemble and link) the above code, use:
`gcc test.s -o test.exe`

Here are some clarifications and highlights about this approach:

1. **Bypassing `__main`**: Instead of invoking the `__main` function, which is compiler-specific and might involve some additional initialization, we directly begin with our logic.
2. **Shadow Space**: The code doesn't create a shadow space, which, as mentioned by others, is space on the stack that the called function can use for the four register parameters, home addresses on 64-bit Windows.
3. **Graceful Exit**: We've incorporated the C `exit` function to ensure a proper exit.
4. **Use of `lea` vs. `movabs`**: By using the RIP-relative addressing mode with `lea`, we're making the code position-independent, which can be advantageous for various reasons, including shared libraries or relocatable code.

While this code may not showcase practices for every scenario or optimization strategies, it simplifies the process, making it more understandable and less cluttered, and still produces the desired output message.

Comment: This actually works?  I'd have expected `puts` to crash if called without calling `__main` to initialize libc data structures, including stdio buffers.  Maybe that's only truly needed if statically linking, if modern MinGW libc has a DLL init function that also runs internal initializers, like glibc on Linux does.

Comment: You're calling `puts` with a misaligned RSP.  It could crash for that reason, but only happens not to.  You could `jmp puts` to tail-call it, implementing `return puts(msg);`.  Or if you want to let `main`'s return address get destroyed like you're doing (by not reserving shadow space) you could `sub $8, %rsp` instead of `sub $40, %rsp`.

Comment: `xor %eax, %eax` / `ret` from main (with RSP pointing to a return address that wasn't overwritten by being part of callees shadow space) *does* exit cleanly, and is guaranteed by the C standard to be equivalent to `call exit`.  `main`'s caller has to be something like `exit(main(argc, argv))`.  So `call exit` isn't needed for a clean exit unless you mess up (or intentionally "optimize") the handling of stack space and make it impossible for your function to return.  That's an option for main but not a good learning exercise because most functions do need to return.

Comment: The `ret` after `call exit` is 100% useless; it's unreachable because `exit` won't return.  Also, `xor %ecx, %ecx` - that zeros the full 64-bit RCX more efficiently, and the arg to `exit` is only a 32-bit integer anyway. [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617)

Comment: Also, `.extern` is ignored by GAS.  It's not an error and I guess some people might do that to inform other humans which symbols you reference, but undeclared symbols are assumed extern.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Extern.html

Comment: @PeterCordes consider posting a full answer, provided with exactly what you would do, I would be very greatful for it...

Comment: The asm I'm recommending is pretty much exactly what you'll get from `gcc -O2 -S hello.c`.  Oh, and Godbolt has MinGW GCC installed.  https://godbolt.org/z/4x1PYvc3r shows it with [options to minimize directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) that aren't strictly necessary.  The .ident and .def stuff isn't necessary AFAIK.  The instructions for `main` are the bare minimum to obey the ABI and still be able to `ret`.  (And to call libc's `__main` init function which is apparently something mingw programs are supposed to do.)

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer.

Comment: @starball I only used it to format, since I am not a native english speaker, I hope it made the answer better.

Comment: @ugo_capeto Hello! While I understand that you wrote the actual answer here, using AI to reword answers is also prohibited, and formatting likely falls under that. If you want, you can post the version that did not use AI, but this one is in violation of the AI policy for Stack Overflow. If that doesn't make sense or you'd like clarification, feel free to ping me and I can try to clarify. Thank you!