# Calling functions inside shellcode

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, shellcode

I would like to compile small `double(...)` functions as x64 shellcode. I already have a working program to generate the encoded assembly for simple math operations like `a + b / a`, where `a` and `b` are `double` parameters for the function.

The generated code is loaded into a executable `mmap` buffer and can be called later.

I have the following problem: I would like to call `math.h` functions like `sin`, `exp` etc. inside my generated shellcode. Since all `call` opcodes somehow use 32-bit adresses or relative jumps, i cannot easily use these instructions. Therefore I tried to implement my own `call`-instruction this way:

```
lea rax, [rip+0x0] ;load instruction pointer into rax
add rax, <offset-to-return-to>
push rax

moveabs rax, <adress-of-function> ;load the function pointer to rax
jmp rax
```

This is my code to generate these instructions:

```
//lea rax, [rip+0x0]
insertAll(code,std::list<uint8_t>{ 0x48, 0x8D, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 });
//add rax, <offset-to-return-to>
insertAll(code,std::list<uint8_t>{ 0x48, 0x83, 0xC0, <offset-to-return-to>});

//push rax
code.push_back(0x50);

//moveabs rax, address-of-function
uint8_t reg = 0; //rax
uint8_t rexWPrefix = 0x48 + (reg > 8);
uint8_t opCode = 0xB8 + (reg % 8);
insertAll(code,std::list<uint8_t>{ rexWPrefix, opCode });
code.insert(code.end(),reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&fabs),reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&fabs) + 8);

//jmp rax
insertAll(code,std::list<uint8_t>{ 0xFF, 0xE0 });
```

Unfortunately, calling functions this way does not work, the program crashes with a `SIGSEGV` error. Is there something wrong with my assembly code or encoding of the instruction? What value should `<offset-to-return-to>` have, to let the function return to the right position?

Disclaimer: I know, that this is not the best way to handle dynamic generation of code... I could just compile a dynamic library and load it with `dlsym`. This is just a fun way to learn about assembly/shellcodes and should not be taken too seriously :)

Comment: Makes sense at first glance, use a debugger to see where and why it faults. PS: you can of course merge the `add rax` into the `lea`. Make sure you use correct offset.

Comment: What is "x64 shellcode"?? And C and C++ are different languages. Don't spam tags.

Comment: @Olaf : I wanted to say, that I use x86-64 instructions for the code. This might be important for the jmp instruction because the adress size is 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

I found three errors. The `jmp` instruction is not absolute, but afaik `RIP`-relative. I used `push + ret` as an alternative because `ret` jumps to an absolute address lying on the stack.

Additionally, I did not know that it is mandatory for the caller to reserve 4*8 bytes shadow space on the stack. The details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190132/what-is-the-shadow-space-in-x64-assembly).

Finally, the code to insert the function pointer into the instruction code was wrong. I accidentally inserted the first 8 bytes of the function code instead of the value of the pointer:

```
code.insert(code.end(),reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&fabs),reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&fabs) + 8);
```

This is the finished working code:

```
//add rsp,0x20  --> shadow space of 4*8 bytes
insertAll(code,std::list<uint8_t>{ 0x48, 0x83, 0xC4, 0x20 } );
//lea rax, [rip+0x0]
insertAll(code,std::list<uint8_t>{ 0x48, 0x8D, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 });
//add rax, 18
insertAll(code,std::list<uint8_t>{ 0x48, 0x83, 0xC0, 18 });
//push rax
code.push_back(0x50);

//moveabs rax, address-of-function
uint8_t reg = 0; //rax
uint8_t rexWPrefix = 0x48 + (reg > 8);
uint8_t opCode = 0xB8 + (reg % 8);
insertAll(code,std::list<uint8_t>{ rexWPrefix, opCode });
void* address = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&my_abs);
code.insert(code.end(),reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&address),reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&address) + sizeof(address));

//push rax
code.push_back(0x50);
//retq
code.push_back(0xC3);
//sub rsp,0x20  --> shadow space of 4*8 bytes
insertAll(code,std::list<uint8_t>{ 0x48, 0x83, 0xEC, 0x20 } );
```