# Using push/pop around function calls on Windows x64

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, att, stack-memory

I am fairly new to assembly and architectures so I was playing around with the GCC to assemble my assembler file.
I am running Windows 10, with AMD 3750H (IDK if this helps)

It is a fairly simple program, that does the following:

1. Creates a stack frame
2. Pushes two numbers to the stack
3. Pops them one at a time, calling printf once for each.  (So the last pop is after the first call)
4. exits

Here is the code I wrote:

```
.data
form:
  .ascii "%d\n\0";

.text
.globl main

main:
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  subq $32, %rsp;

  pushq $420;
  pushq $69;

  lea form(%rip) , %rcx;
  xor %eax, %eax
  popq %rdx
  call printf

  lea form(%rip) , %rcx;
  xor %eax, %eax
  popq %rdx
  call printf

  mov %rbp, %rsp
  popq %rbp
  ret
```

But the output I get is (rather strangely):

```
69
4199744
```

---

I read about shadow space in the Windows x64 calling convention but I couldn't find *the proper way* to work with it when using push/pop:

- [What is the 'shadow space' in x64 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190132/what-is-the-shadow-space-in-x64-assembly)
- [gcc output on cygwin using stack space outside stack frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665668/gcc-output-on-cygwin-using-stack-space-outside-stack-frame)

This is what I tried (thanks to Jester) and it worked

```
# subtract 32 when I push
  pushq $420;
  subq $32, %rsp

# Add 32 when I pop

  addq $32, %rsp
  popq %rdx
```

But for some reason I feel there maybe a more elegant way to go about this

Do I have to leave 32 bytes after *every* push?  That seems like a lot of space is being wasted.

Comment: maybe try debugging the value before and after the operation?

Comment: Your pushes end up in the shadow space which is 32 bytes above the return address. You did try to allocate that with the `sub $32, %rsp` but subsequent `push` will put stuff under that.

Comment: Long story short, allocate more space (make sure 16 byte aligned) and use `mov` instructions to the top slots leaving the bottom 32 bytes untouched.

Comment: In Windows x64, a `call` can clobber the 32 bytes above the current RSP; those bytes are owned by the callee.

Comment: I didn't know it was called "shadow space" so I couldn't find anything useful on the internet. @Jester Do I have to leave 32 bytes after every push?? Something like
`pushq $420;
subq $32, %rsp; 
pushq $69;`

I tried this and this  indeed was working. But seems like a lot of space is being wasted

Comment: No, you only have to leave 32 bytes of unused stack for a `call`.  As Jester suggested, you might prefer to just use `mov`, like `mov %eax, 32(%rsp)` to save something in memory before a `call`, if you were using stack-space instead of a call-preserved register.

Comment: Look at compiler output for examples of how to use it for local vars in a non-leaf function.  If you pop again *before* a call, you don't need to do anything special, but in that case you normally wouldn't use push/pop at all.

Comment: FYI, `xor %eax, %eax` is unnecessary even before variadic functions in Windows x64.  Passing AL = number of FP args in XMM regs is only a thing in x86-64 System V (used on all non-Windows systems).