# How to push arguments onto stack using MASM x64?

Tags: c, assembly, masm

I know the x64 calling convention, first four arguments are in `rcx`, `rdx`, `r8`, `r9`, rest are on the stack. But my question is how push these arguments?

```
call_func PROC
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov rbx, rcx ; move C function address to rbx

    mov rcx, 1   ; some dummy value
    mov rdx, 2   ; some dummy value
    mov r8,  3   ; some dummy value
    mov r9,  4   ; some dummy value

    ; and now I want to push fifth argument, but how?

    call rbx     ; call the function

    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp

    ret
call_func ENDP
```

I have tried `mov QWORD PTR [rsp + 20h], 1` but when returning form this asm function the RIP register is set to weird value, like 0x0000000000000001. I know that the RIP register is instruction pointer, but why it is modifying it?
I have tried one more thing, let the function take 6 arguments and when I pass sixth argument like `mov QWORD PTR [rsp + 28h], 1` the app is fine, sixth argument is passed, fifth has weird value.

Comment: You're overwriting values higher up in the stack by doing that. You should look at the `push` instruction.

Comment: You need to allocate stack including the space shadow space first. E.g. do `sub rsp, 48` then you can use your `mov QWORD PTR [rsp + 20h], 1`.

Comment: @Jester Thank you, now it is working, weird because earlier I have tried this, but maybe without ```mov QWORD PTR [rsp + 20h], 1```

Answer (score 1):

As [Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester) said, before pushing arguments I need to allocate space for these arguments including [shadow space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190132/what-is-the-shadow-space-in-x64-assembly).
Final working code:

```
call_func PROC
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32  ; allocate shadow space 'padding'
    sub rsp, 16  ; allocate space for fifth and sixth argument

    mov r11, rcx ; move C function address to r11

    mov rcx, 1   ; some dummy value
    mov rdx, 2   ; some dummy value
    mov r8,  3   ; some dummy value
    mov r9,  4   ; some dummy value

    mov QWORD PTR [rsp + 20h], 5  ; push fifth argument
    mov QWORD PTR [rsp + 28h], 6  ; push sixth argument

    call r11     ; call the function

    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp

    ret
call_func ENDP
```

Comment: There is no reason to use two `sub` instructions. More importantly, `rbx` is callee-saved register you should not use that for your temporary.

Comment: I know, it is just cleaner for newbies like me. And you are right, I forgot about ```rbx```, but I guess I can just push it on stack and then pop it?

Comment: You can but then you have to worry about alignment. You do have an extra stack slot available since you only use 5 arguments. Anyway, simplest is to pick another register that does not need to be preserved.

Comment: A quick&dirty alternative: load first four arguments to their registers, align RSP and then 
`PUSH Sixth, Fifth, R9, R8, RDX, RCX`  before `CALL`.

Comment: You can write `sub rsp, 32 + 16    ;  shadow space + arg space` if you want.

Comment: Or if you want to write `sub rsp, 32`, use `push` *before* that to write the two args.  Since you have an even number of stack args, and an odd number of pushes of call-preserved registers (just RBP), that still restores 16-byte stack alignment.