Assembly code, printf and allocating space on the stack
I am in the process of writing 64-bit assembly code for the Pentium. I am using Microsoft Visual C/C++ and MASM. In assembly code, I wrote the following code fragment to call printf:
push    rcx
push    rdx
push    rdi
push    rsi

lea rcx,string1
call    printf

pop rsi
pop rdi
pop rdx
pop rcx

where string1 is defined as: string1   db  "start of func", 10, 0.
I expected the first four instructions to save four registers on the stack. That is, the values of the saved registers would be restored by the four pop instructions. However, the register  values were not being properly restored. I found this video:
Link on calling printf
This video says that before calling printf you need to allocate 32 bytes on the stack for these values. Hence, I wrote this code:
push    rcx
push    rdx
push    rdi
push    rsi

sub rsp,20
lea rcx,string1
call    printf
add rsp,20h

pop rsi
pop rdi
pop rdx
pop rcx

This code works and makes some sense to me. When I look at the code generated by the C compiler it does not allocate any additional space on the stack and it works. Therefore, I do not understand why I need to allocate additional space on the stack. Please tell me what I am missing.

Not an answer, but subtracting 20 then adding 20h to rsp seems broken to me.

Yes, you need to allocate shadow space. Pretty sure the compiler also did this, but probably not where you were looking. Also if that's all your code you are still misaligning the stack, you want 28h not 20h. PS: rcx and rdx don't need to be preserved per convention only do it if you need it for your own purposes.

The compiler likely subtracts a large number from rsp at the beginning of the function, leaving enough shadow space for subsequent function calls.  That's why you don't see it subtract and add around all the function calls.

@pmacfarlane You are right. I have a typo in the post. Not the code. I will fix it.

Feel free to edit the typo!

@Jester You are right. The compiler generated code had a big subtract to RSP and  the  start of the function.

Also when I am calling a standard  C  function in assemble language, how do I  know how much stack space to allocate for the function. Is  it  related to the number  of arguments the function  takes? In this case, I am only passing in one argument.

The shadow space is fixed at 32 bytes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190132/what-is-the-shadow-space-in-x64-assembly.

If using Visual Studio 2015 or later, printf() is normally included into a compiled C  or C++ program. If you are writing stand-alone assembly code with no C or C++ source files, you will need to use the legacy library for functions like printf(), scanf(): includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib .

From the fact that you are passing a value in rcx, it appears you are using the windows calling conventions, rather than the "standard" calling conventions used by everyone except microsoft.
For the Windows x64 calling convetions, when calling a varargs function (which printf is) you must allocate 32 bytes of "shadow" space on the stack immediately above1 the return address.  There doesn't need to be anything in this space, but you can't (reliably) store anything there, as the called function may clobber it -- that is in fact what is happening to your saved register values in your first fragment.

1"above" since the stack grows downward means allocated before the call

Note that shadow space must be allocated for all functions not just varargs.
