# How can I print a character in CMD using assembler (Windows 64 Bits)

Tags: windows, assembly, printing, character, nasm

I would like to know how to print a character in CMD (Windows 8.1 64 bits).

I would like to do this without using GCC (I would like to use only NASM) or without using DosBox.

Comment: I'm trying to learn NASM, but most tutorials uses DosBox or GCC and I would like to know how to print a caracter on CMD

Comment: Use Windows' [console functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: See this answer to a somewhat similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/1029093/3857942