# Call functions from x86_64 assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, jit, machine-code

I am trying to create my own JIT and so far managed to run very simple assembly code (in machine-code), but having trouble figuring out how to call functions this way. In Visual Studio I can see functions in disassembly window.

Another related question is how do I call Win32 MessageBox() in machine-code?

Next question is how do I call external DLL/LIB functions in this manner?

Also is there any books or tutorials which could teach me further in this subject? I have tried to search for it but get results like .NET, JVM and LLVM which I think is not really what I am looking for.

Here is a simplified version of the code that I am working on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // b8 03 00 00 00 83 c0 02 c3
    unsigned char code[] = {
        0xb8,                   // mov eax, 3
        0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 3 (32 bit)
        0x83,                   // add eax, 2 // 0x83 = add,
        0xc0,                   // ModR/M with immediate 8 bit value
        0x02,                   // 2 (8 bit)
        0xc3                    // ret
    };

    void* mem = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof(code), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    memcpy(mem, code, sizeof(code));

    DWORD old;
    VirtualProtect(mem, sizeof(mem), PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, &old);

    int(*func)() = reinterpret_cast<int(*)()>(mem);

    printf("Number is %d\n", func());

    VirtualFree(mem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to have the JIT assembly code to call a C++ function?

Before this project I made a byte-code interpreter in C++, but I wasn't really happy with the speed when comparing it to equivalent test program in C#. C# was roughly 25x times faster. So I stumbled on something called JIT to make it faster. So I hope you all can see where I am taking this JIT project. And maybe if possible make it handle GUI.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Gazillion examples around, maybe look at a [hello world](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1032422/547981) for starters. Assembling it by hand will not be fun though. Note that function calls are unlikely to be your bottleneck.

Comment: I generally write a sample program in C / C++, then have the compiler output assembly code in order to get the assembly level names and calling sequence. In the case of Visual Studio 2015, printf is now part of an include file, meaning it effectively gets inlined with C / C++ code. One way to deal with this is to have a  project that include a C file for the printf, and an assembly file for the rest of the project. There may be an option to import specific libraries that still include the old style printf.

Comment: Well, IIRC, it's possible to bend clang to compile C source into memory, and then JIT it by LLVM into machine code and run it, so by studying LLVM sources you would probably get your answers.. in few years... It's also unclear to me why you are bothered by interpreted language speed, simply write performance parts in C++ and assembly, the JIT will generally be hardly on-par in best case, and underperform in any properly tuned performance case. For non-performance critical parts the 25x shouldn't matter either. Although this may be good exercise to make you figure out how cool C++ is. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably find some tutorials about writing a compiler/linker. It may help with implementing/calling dynamic libraries.

I'm not sure what you exactly mean by calling C++ functions. Anyway I wrote the following demo program that you can take a look and see if it helps at all.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

__int64 sub(__int64 a, __int64 b)
{
    return a - b;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char code[] =
    {
        0x48, 0x89, 0xC8,           // mov rax, rcx
        0xC3,                       // ret

        0x48, 0x83, 0xEC, 0x20,     // sub rsp, 0x20
        0xFF, 0xD0,                 // call rax
        0x48, 0x83, 0xC4, 0x20,     // add rsp, 0x20
        0xC3                        // ret
    };


    char *mem = static_cast<char *>(VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof(code), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE));

    MoveMemory(mem, code, sizeof(code));

    auto setFunc = reinterpret_cast<void *(*)(void *)>(mem);
    auto callFunc = reinterpret_cast<__int64 (*)(__int64, __int64)>(mem + 4);

    setFunc(sub);
    __int64 r = callFunc(0, 1);
    cout << "r = " << r << endl;

    VirtualFree(mem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);


    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you prevent C++ from polluting `rax` between `setFunc(sub);` and `__int64 r = callFunc(0, 1);`? IMO this is not a stable example (although it may work with reasonably low optimization level and enough luck).

Comment: @Ped7g My point is not that you can just use the code as is. If you can call a function directly why would you do it this way anyway. I meant to say you can retrieve the address of a function this way and then you can do whatever you want with it, setting up a jump table, for example.

Comment: @MegaStupidMonkeys This is what I really was interested in. Thank you!