# Printing hello world in nasm windows

Tags: windows, nasm

What would the equivalent nasm would be in windows without using any libraries?

```
section .text
   global _start

_start:          
   mov  edx,len  
   mov  ecx,msg  
   mov  ebx,1    
   mov  eax,4  
   int  0x80 

   mov  eax,1  
   int  0x80    

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa 
len equ $ - msg
```

I read that _start is replaced with _main in windows but what about the system call? I found this table but im not sure which register gets what argument:

http://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/32/

Im especially confused about how to understand the system calls in windows because in linux its really clear what to do:

https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/

The documentation for windows assembly, especially the system calls seems really really poor.

Comment: the name of entry point not play any role here, but `int  0x80` not worked in windows

Comment: @RbMm so what is the right way?

Comment: use windows api

Comment: You question is pretty involved to give a proper answer, so google `nasm windows` and you'll find all kinds of information and examples.

Comment: @Shift_Left hard to find good info for starters like me but I will try. Thank you : )

Comment: @Shift_Left is this a good resource? http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.13.02/html/nasmdoc0.html

Comment: @Asperger - this not related to nasm at all. this is only tool. you need knowledge about windows system programming

Comment: @RbMm oh ok. Is it just me or is windows far more complex than linux for assembly starters?

Comment: This thread has a few good examples of where to start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023593/how-to-write-hello-world-in-assembler-under-windows