# How do debuggers keep track of the mapping between C code and assembly instructions?

Tags: debugging, gcc, assembly

I was wondering how debuggers are able to step line by line through the source code.

Once the source code is compiled and I run the program, how does a debugger know the correspondence between the machine-level instructions and the higher-level statements?

For example, if I set a break-point on one line in my source file, how does it know which machine-level instruction to stop at?

Comment: The compiler can emit debug information if requested, e.g. using `gcc -g`. If it's not present (either because it wasn't there to start with or was later stripped) then the debugger won't be able to map source code.

Comment: The compiler keeps notes.

Comment: understand that optimized code doesnt have a one to one / one to group relationship with the high level language.  it is for the most part smoke and mirrors, notes are taken as described in the answers, but the reality is you are not stepping through "lines" of C code, it is more of a rough estimate.  Ideally you want to step through the machine code/asm if you feel the need to use a debugger.

Comment: also note that each toolchain is different, so at best this would be a gcc answer due to you tagging gcc.  other than not being a stackoverflow question anyway, it is also too broad.

Answer (score 4):

Look at asm output from `gcc -g -S` and you'll see `.line` debug-info directives and so on for the block of asm corresponding to the C source line.

(With optimization enabled the same line can map to multiple *non-contiguous* instructions, so it gets much trickier, but compilers still try to be useful and map most instructions to some source line even if they're really the result of optimization and doing an operation that doesn't appear in the source...).

https://godbolt.org/ uses the same debug info as debuggers do, but uses it for color highlighting to match source lines with asm.

---

When an assembler assembles these `.line` directives, it creates debug info in the `.o` object file, which is eventually linked into an executable or library.  Or split into a separate debug-symbols file.  Or stripped.

It's this debug-info that debuggers read.

(Debug info also includes info about which named C variables are stored where, and what their types are.  For locals, the locations are relative to the stack frame for the function that contains them.)

Comment: WOW! This `goodbolt` reference! I had no idea such incredible tool existed! Only randomly found it through your answer. I guess now there is no other option for me but to dive in the depths of assembler...

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer: Matt Godbolt (who created that site) gave a talk at CppCon2017, [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)”, so that and   [How to write hello world in assembler under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1023593) are a good starting point for diving in.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler & linker can produce so called debug symbols that contains this information. The debug information contains the source file/line to address mapping, the addresses of global variables and beginning addresses of all the functions and their local variable offsets on the stack. In the case of gcc, the -g compiler option does this. The debug symbol information can be embedded in the executable program as typically is the case with gcc or in separate symbol files (.pdb files with msvc).