# unable to run assemble exe file

Tags: assembly, exe, cmp

I'm trying to print hello word with assembly on Windows 10. 
I successfully converted the object file to executable file
with `nasm -f elf64 hello.asm` and `ld hello.o -o hello` but
when I run the file nothing print on screen .

My code:

```
section .text
   global _start     ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:             ;tells linker entry point
   mov  edx,len     ;message length
   mov  ecx,msg     ;message to write
   mov  ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

   mov  eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;string to be printed
len equ $ - msg     ;length of the string
```

Comment: `int 0x80` is for 32-bit Linux. You'll have to use Windows API functions, such as `WriteConsole` if you want this to run on Windows.

Comment: And in case you are using WSL, that only supports 64 bit so find a 64 bit example.

Comment: i used windows api and evrything work fine  i joind alink that solved my problem in the comment below thank you all for the  help

Comment: i used windows api and evrything worked fine  i joind a link to somone who solved my problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023593/how-to-write-hello-world-in-assembler-under-windows thank you all for the help

Comment: @karam Cool!  I've marked that question as a duplicate of yours because it answers the question you had.  If you have further questions, feel free to make a new question.