# How to compile simple assembly windows program?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, assembly

I'm trying to compile such a simple `assembly` Hello World program:

```
    global  _main
    extern  _printf

    section .text
_main:
    push    message
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    ret
message:
    db  'Hello, Worldsssss', 10, 0
```

I'd like to compile it using just the `ml.exe` from my `MSVC 2019` installation but when i run just:

```
ml .\HelloWorld_5.asm
```

I'm getting:

```
.\HelloWorld_5.asm(8) : error A2008:syntax error : global
.\HelloWorld_5.asm(9) : error A2008:syntax error : in directive
.\HelloWorld_5.asm(11) : error A2008:syntax error : section
.\HelloWorld_5.asm(12) : error A2034:must be in segment block
.\HelloWorld_5.asm(13) : error A2034:must be in segment block
.\HelloWorld_5.asm(14) : error A2034:must be in segment block
.\HelloWorld_5.asm(15) : error A2034:must be in segment block
.\HelloWorld_5.asm(16) : error A2034:must be in segment block
.\HelloWorld_5.asm(17) : error A2034:must be in segment block
.\HelloWorld_5.asm(18) : error A2034:must be in segment block
.\HelloWorld_5.asm(18) : error A2088:END directive required at end of file
```

Please don't tell me to use the `masm.exe`, I'd like to use `ml`

What option to usue with the `ml` to compile without a problems?

Comment: That's NASM (or FASM) syntax, not MASM, so there are no options that would let any version of MASM assemble it (including `ml`).

Comment: @Peter Cordes Ok I understand but can You please provide me the simplest Hello World program with printf function to compile with the MASM (ml.exe)?

Comment: Why would you need `printf` just to print a static string? Use  `WriteConsole` or `MessageBox`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, but I'm just curious how such simple Hello World using the printf would look like in the MASM version...

Comment: Then go search for that instead.  There's a MASM answer on [How to write hello world in assembler under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032422).  There are MASM `printf` examples elsewhere on SO, if changing that to pass args to printf instead of MessageBoxA or WriteConsole.