# How to call Windows API in x64 MASM program

Tags: c, assembly, winapi, x86-64, masm

I am using MASM in x64 Windows operating system. I wanted to call Windows APIs and then output some strings to the screen.

I am learning x64 assembly programming in Windows operating system. Today I wanted to print some result to the console. However, unlike linux operating system, in windows we can use syscalls directly without any pain. I've written the following program to print a hello world message to the console but it doesn't show anything. I couldn't figure out what is wrong with this code.

```
GetStdHandle PROTO
ExitProcess PROTO
WriteConsoleA PROTO

.data
    message         DB "Hello World",0
    message_size    DW SIZEOF message

.code
    main PROC
        SUB RSP, 5 * 8  
        
        MOV RCX, -11           
        CALL GetStdHandle

        MOV RCX, RAX     
        LEA RDX, message
        MOV R8, SIZEOF message - 1
        LEA R9, message_size  
        MOV  QWORD PTR [RSP + 4 * SIZEOF QWORD], 0
        CALL WriteConsoleA

        MOV RCX, 0      
        CALL ExitProcess
    main ENDP
END
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write hello world in assembly under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023593/how-to-write-hello-world-in-assembly-under-windows)

Comment: Generally I write a C program and have Visual Studio produce assembly code so I can see the actual code used for the Windows API.

Comment: The code looks correct (including stack alignment, home space, and parameter usage). I have assembled and linked the code here and had it run correctly. What options did you pass to the assembler and linker to produce the program?

Comment: @vitsoft `message_size` is a DWORD as parameter 4 is a pointer to that DWORD (LPDWORD) so at a minimum it should be changed to DD (DQ is extra). The 5th parameter which is on the stack is zeroed out with `MOV  QWORD PTR [RSP + 4 * SIZEOF QWORD], 0`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I think that `LEA R9, message_size` should load the 4th parameter with 64bit address pointing at 64bit memory variable, but it points at 16bit variable only. However, it might work anyway.

Comment: It is an LPDWORD so it is a pointer to a DWORD (32-bit value). The pointer is 64-bit but the data it points at should be at least 32-bits (DWORD). So a minimum would be DD, but DQ would work too but it is an extra 4 unneeded bytes. The `LEA` instruction is properly loading the 64-bit pointer into R9. While pointer sizes changed in 64-bit Windows to 64-bit, the width/size of a WORD&DWORD did not.

Comment: probably main error really in not *CUI* subsystem. however much better use `EXTERN __imp_SomeAPI:QWORD` for function declaration, instead `SomeAPI PROTO`, `message` can be in `.CONST` section, and message_size must be local variable in stack. and of course need check result of api calls

Comment: @RbMm : Yep that was my opinion as well, which is why I wanted to know which options they were using when running the linker.

Comment: @MichaelPetch You're right, 64bit WriteConsole writes 32 bits only to the variable specified by 4th parameter, I just verified this in x64dbg.  To make the program work, I had to **change segment name** from `.code` to  `.text`. It seems that linker doesn;t grant .code segment with RX privilege.

Comment: @vitsoft - no, task not in segment name. and no in execute flag.  `.CODE` is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you linking it as a console app? Windows distinguishes between console apps that write to stdout (which is what yours is doing) and GUI apps that create windows and run a message loop.

You need to specify `/subsystem:console` as a linker flag. There might be a MASM option/directive that does the same.

Comment: An aplication linked to graphic subsystem creates a new console. Nevertheless, in this case the console window is destroyed instantly when the program exits, usually before the user is able to read it.

Comment: @vitsoft *An aplication linked to graphic subsystem creates a new console.* only if code call `AllocConsole` and here no such call

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine after [adding an assembler-language file to an existing Visual Studio C++ project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/masm-for-x64-ml64-exe?view=msvc-170#to-add-an-assembler-language-file-to-an-existing-visual-studio-c-project), a console `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` X64 application.
[image]